# yum IUS in Amazon Linux 2

Tags: python, yum, amazon

As I'll need to install the layrst version of Python, will need to install a particular repository - Inline with Upstream Stable (IUS) - that provides rpm packages for new versions of selected software.

If I was using CentOS 7, would run

```
yum -y install https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
```

and then for installing Python would do something like

```
yum -y install python36u
```

If I try to run the initial command, then I get in the first command

[image]

> Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
>
> Cannot open: https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm. Skipping.
>
> Error: Nothing to do

and in the second

> Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
> amzn2-core                                           | 3.7 kB  00:00:00
>
> No package python36u available.
> Error: Nothing to do

All in all,

[image]

---

Considering I'm now using Amazon Linux 2,

```
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
```

[image: Amazon 2 instead of CentOS]

what would be the equivalent commands for Amazon Linux 2?

Comment: Have you to follow the CentOS steps? AFAIK Amazon Linux is based on RHEL so it might just work.

Comment: @VojtechTrefny good idea. I just updated the question with that information

Comment: `Cannot open: https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm. Skipping.`

I think there is a problem with the URL -- it's not working, maybe the server is down temporarily?

Comment: @VojtechTrefny you're right. According to the documentation, it changed. You're welcome to write that as an answer and I'll add the screenshoots. Basically I had to run `sudo yum install https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm` as stated [here](https://ius.io/setup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer base on discussion with @Tiago in the comments to help other with similar issue:
Amazon Linux is based on CentOS 7 so the repository should work there. The repository has been moved https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm so the correct command to enable is

```
sudo yum install https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

[image]

Once you install it, you can run the following command just fine

```
yum -y install python36u
```

[image]

Source: https://ius.io/setup

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not doing it for the bounty.